# something about elem function in a list

Tags: haskell

I have some issues about elem function.
The elem function can return a bool value when the list contains the specific value. eg. elem 1 [1,2,3,5] return true.

The question is if the list is made up with string. For instance the list is ['A2','A1']. how can I use the elem function.  I used elem 'A2' ['A1','A2'] but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you intend to use `Strings` (aka `[Char]` in haskell), but you are not using the proper sintax, check the difference here:

```
Prelude Data.List> :t 'A'
'A' :: Char
Prelude Data.List> :t "A"
"A" :: [Char]
```

Now lets take the type signature of `elem`:

```
Prelude Data.List> :t elem
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

Let's check now about `Foldable` and `Eq`, `Eq a` means that `a` type can be check for equality,and, lets simply think of foldable as a collection, or data structure that can be visited element by element for now. 
So, we have that `elem` takes an item of type `a`, a "collection" of type `a` and return a `Bool`, so, if we have a collection of `[Char]` we need to provide an element of the same type.
Now, as mentioned before, if we use string, and a list of strings, our "final" `elem` type would be `[Char] -> [[Char]] -> Bool`. Lets try it:

```
Prelude Data.List> elem "A1" ["A1", "A2"]
True
```